# Need help to handle this error: Variable 'x' used before being initialized

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a problem in Swift whit optional function param. I want to set an value for an SKSpriteNote within a function, but this value dos not exist before the function is called, so i obviously get an error ;/

Can anyone please tell me what to do, to solve this?

**THIS IS THE ERROR I GET:**
Variable 'bought_ingredient_market_graphic' used before being initialized

**THIS IS MY FUNCTION** (see

```
func show_market_graphic(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, level: String, ingredient: String?){

    var market_graphic: SKSpriteNode

    var bought_ingredient_market_graphic: SKSpriteNode

    if(level == "locked"){

        market_graphic = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "locked_ingredient")

    } else {

        market_graphic = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bought_ingredient")

        bought_ingredient_market_graphic = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: ingredient!)
    }

    market_graphic.zPosition = 10

    market_graphic.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

    addChild(market_graphic)

    if(level != "locked"){
        // * ERROR ON LINE BELOW
        bought_ingredient_market_graphic.zPosition = 20
        // * ERROR ON LINE BELOW
        bought_ingredient_market_graphic.position = market_graphic.position
        // * ERROR ON LINE BELOW
        addChild(bought_ingredient_market_graphic)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you move the declaration and assignment of bought_ingredient_market_graphic into the second if-block, where it is actually needed?

Comment: I can't not tell you why, it's late??? :/ Thanks Matrin... Time for some sleep :)

Comment: did that change fix the problem that occured?

Comment: Yes i does Korpel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would consider using an enum when passing in the parameter "level" into the function. This will help fix possible logic issues within your function.

Where your problem probably lies: If you do not pass in a non-nil ingredient String, you will encounter an error when accessing or using `bought_ingredient_market_graphic`. You could have a typo in your string that you use to initialize your image. Make sure your string matches your image name. This is likely what is happening.

Also why not try initializing your sprite in the else logic?

```
func show_market_graphic(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, level: String, ingredient: String?) {

   var market_graphic: SKSpriteNode

   var bought_ingredient_market_graphic: SKSpriteNode

   if level == "locked" {

      market_graphic = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "locked_ingredient")

   } else {

      market_graphic = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bought_ingredient")

      bought_ingredient_market_graphic = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: ingredient!)
      bought_ingredient_market_graphic.zPosition = 20
      bought_ingredient_market_graphic.position = market_graphic.position
      addChild(bought_ingredient_market_graphic)

   }

   market_graphic.zPosition = 10
   market_graphic.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
   addChild(market_graphic)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work in principle, the compiler fails to detect the corelation between `level == "locked"` and `level != "locked"`.

I assume that the compiler sees a risk that the value of level could change betwwen the statelents.  So the best way would be to initialize `bought_ingredient_market_graphic` in the first if-clause.